# react setState doesnot work properly

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutability, setstate

i do ve nested objects in state, where i should update data with dynamic key and value. for which i ve used React's immutability helpers *set* operation.

my sample code:

```
var update = require('react-addons-update');

var myState = update(this.state, {
  data:  {[dynamic_keys]: {$set: dynamic_values}}
});

this.setState(myState);
```

Problem is setState not updating state in once, in twice click it is updating state but not in one.. what's the best way to deal with this problem?? or is there any other tricks to setState in react ??

Comment: This question is not particularly clear. It might be more useful if you could describe what it is you're hoping to accomplish and provide more of your code (for example it is not clear in which function this code is being executed).

Comment: @DaveDraper my code is executed on inputbox onChanged, my main concern or say dissatisfaction is why this react setState immediately doesnot show changes in state..

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in your code to check that the call to setState is actually being executed on the first click? If this is an onChanged event handler on an input element then are you sure that this event is actually being triggered (what type have you assigned the input element?)

Comment: input type was number

Answer (score 0):

First of all "setState()" doesn't work synchronously. It will take a small time set the state even after it's execution since it is an asynchronous function. The best solution i will using using setState's second parameter. 
Here is a sample example.

```
stateFunction(data){
    this.setState({
        data
        },
        () => {console.log(this.state.data)
    })
}
```